# Show next day using getDay()

Tags: javascript

I need a way to show the next day of the week using getDay();

Without thinking too much I used:

```
var d = new Date();
var weekday = d.getDay() +1;
```

Then I realized this will work on most of the days except for Saturday. Since Saturday is the 6th day, if I add one it will return 7 instead of 0, being Sunday.

How would I go about this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var weekday = (d.getDay() + 1) % 7
```

The modulo operator returns the remainder of the division by 7, so that if the result would be 7 (6+1), the modulo of `7 % 7 === 0`

Comment: Well, that was fast and I should really pay more attention :) Makes sense that this would work :) Thanks and have a nice day. Will accept as soon as it will let me :)

Answer (score 2):

Just another option for you:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1); // Note this is "date", not "day"
var weekday = d.getDay();
```

...since JavaScript's `Date` is smart about rollover.

Comment: Thanks TJ, nice to have/know other ways of doing this. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var weekday = d.getDay() === 6 ? 0 : d.getDay()+1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) Have a nice day.